# Symfony3 - No route found for "GET/home"

Tags: php, symfony

I am following this tutorial to set up my first page in a Symfony 3 project: [Joyful Development with Symfony 3 Tutorial](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony/first-page#play)

I created a `HomeController` file in `/src/AppBundle/Controller/`. The contents of this file are:

```
 <?php

 namespace AppBundle\Controller;

 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 class HomeController {

  /**
   * @Route("/home")
   */

  public function showAction() {
      return new Response('Testing!');
  }
 }
```

I am simply trying to get the text: "Testing!" from the `showAction()` function above to display. However, my page has an error: No route found for "GET /home"

Is there something wrong with my setup above? Sorry if this is a simple question, this is my first time working with Symfony and I am lost!

[image: Symfony Error Message]

Comment: Not sure what the guide has covered as far as server setup goes, but do you have the proper htaccess file and server configuration?

Comment: @samrap thanks for your reply. My .htaccess file is: `<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
`

Comment: Here's the [link for Nginx configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are testing on localhost, you can go to your project directory and use the built-in web server to test your project:

```
php bin/console server:start
```

and to stop it:

```
php bin/console server:stop
```

To debug routes, enter:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

That should display all your routes. Once this works, it's a matter of getting your Nginx working.

You can also specify a different IP address for the built-in server. See the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html#starting-the-web-server

Answer (score 2):

Based on your `htaccess` file my guess is that you don't have the proper rewrites in your htaccess file. The way routing works, from a really high level, is that you always hit the same file and the code parses the URL and calls the proper route. In order for that to work, you need to tell your server how to do it.

First, see [Configuring a Web Server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) to make sure your server is configured properly.

Then, try adding this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This should fix your issue. If not, have a look at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/alch/7766993).

Disclaimer: I have not worked much *directly* with the Symfony framework, I work mainly in Laravel which is built on top of Symfony. I've played around with Symfony Components but never built a full project in Symfony. You may have to tweak the htaccess config a bit from the examples I posted, but this should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry in advance if this is a dumb question. I am working on an Nginx server. In what directory should I put the Nginx configuration code in my application for it to work properly?

Comment: Good question, I'm not familiar with nginx :/ Was this not helpful for you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx ? As for the htaccess file, it should be placed in your project's public `web` directory in any case

Comment: Gotcha. Take a look at the nginx docs then, or just Google around for "basic nginx server setup" or something along those lines to see where the file should go :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled routes in the file app/config/routing.yml? The routes need to be imported to be active as any other routing resources.

```
# app/config/routing.yml

# import routes from a controller class
home:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

[More info](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to turn on and off again ? see. IT crowd

In some case the new route hasn't been added to cache so try to delete the project cache at project_name/var/cache and restart your server php bin/console server:run
This fix it for me.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Probable cause is that your project does not have annotations enabled:
see the doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html).

Run this to get it:

```
 composer require annotations
```

It should do the trick. (and maybe after that do a cache:clear)